# Spartacus metatag overwritten by config even if no url is set

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I have a setup with Spartacus v2 (Hybris 2005) in a CCv2 enviroment.
I'm currently facing the issue that the content of the metatag `<meta name="occ-backend-base-url" content="OCC_BACKEND_BASE_URL_VALUE" />` isn't replaced in any of my enviroments.

This happens because I need to set occ prefix in my app.module.ts to with hybris 2005:

```
     backend: {
        occ: {
          prefix: '/occ/v2/'
        }
      }
```

Is there a frontend only solution for this issue or do we need to change the prefix back to /rest/v2 in the backend?

Is there a reason that the meta tag is ignored even if no url is defined in the backend.occ data object, but only the prefix?

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Spartacusstore</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.webmanifest">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#1976d2">
  <meta name="occ-backend-base-url" content="OCC_BACKEND_BASE_URL_VALUE" />
</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to continue using this application.</noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { translations, translationChunksConfig } from '@spartacus/assets';
import { B2cStorefrontModule } from '@spartacus/storefront';
import { OccConfig, I18nModule, TranslatePipe } from '@spartacus/core';

const occConfig: OccConfig = { backend: { occ: {} } };
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    B2cStorefrontModule.withConfig({
      backend: {
        occ: {
          prefix: '/occ/v2/'
        }
      },
      checkout: {
        guest: true
      },
      context: {
        currency: ['USD'],
        language: ['en'],
        baseSite: ['electronics-spa']
      },
      i18n: {
        resources: translations,
        chunks: translationChunksConfig,
        fallbackLang: 'en'
      },
      features: {
        level: '2.0'
      },
    }),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: I checked app locally and spartacus works correctly. Prefix is picked from the static configuration and backend ulr is picked from the html meta tag. Can you check this scenario locally as well? If it works for you locally then you can raise the issue in CCv2

Comment: @MarcinLasak thanks for the reply, I have the same issue locally, which version of spartacus are you using?

Comment: I was testing that on 2.1.0. I put the url in the meta tag and everything worked. Did you expected that the meta tag is automatically replaced even locally?